# box2d: revolute damping

Tags: box2d

I've noticed slight damping in revolute joints, but many can still swing virtually forever. Is there any tricks for implementing damping to revolute joints besides coding the friction myself?

Another related question: revolute joints with a "spring" effect (they give way to pressure, but greatly want to return to their original position). Is this supported natively, or will it require a custom coding job?

Comment: You can give the bodies involved some linear damping, would give almost the same result.

Comment: For the spring effect, you could try adding a weld or motor joint on top of the revolute joint. Weld joints can be made soft with non-zero frequency, and motor joints have a maximum torque setting for returning to the original position.